# Digit 1 is not defined? (ISBN Calculator - Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, calculator, isbn

```
mainmenu = input("Welcome to my ISBN calculator, please select an option\n\
1. Load ISBN Calculator\n\
2. Exit Program\n\
") 


(mainmenu) 

if mainmenu == ("2"):
    print ("The ISBN Calculator will now close, thank you for using!")
    time.sleep(1.5) 
    exit()


elif mainmenu == ("1"):
    ISBN = input(" Please enter the 10 digit number exactly\n\
") 


    Digit1 = int(ISBN[0])*11
    Digit2 = int(ISBN[1])*10
    Digit3 = int(ISBN[2])*9
    Digit4 = int(ISBN[3])*8
    Digit5 = int(ISBN[4])*7
    Digit6 = int(ISBN[5])*6
    Digit7 = int(ISBN[6])*5
    Digit8 = int(ISBN[7])*4
    Digit9 = int(ISBN[8])*3
    Digit10 = int(ISBN[9])*2

sum=(Digit1+Digit2+Digit3+Digit4+Digit5+Digit6+Digit7+Digit8+Digit9+Digit10)

num=sum%11
Digit11=11-num 
if Digit11==10:
    Digit11='X'
    ISBNNumber=str(ISBN)+str(Digit11) 
    print('The ISBN number is -->    ' + ISBNNumber)
```

This is my code and it always comes up with the error of Digit 1 is not defined whenever I try enter my 10 digit number, any help?

Comment: Can not reproduce. Does not print anything though. Can you provide a valid ISBN number for better testing?

Comment: While the code has some room for improvement, also the used formula is wrong - first digit to be multiplied by 1, second by 2 etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ISBN check digit solver, user feedback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21309406/isbn-check-digit-solver-user-feedback)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be work. Indent is important.

```
mainmenu = input("Welcome to my ISBN calculator, please select an option\n\
1. Load ISBN Calculator\n\
2. Exit Program\n\
")

if mainmenu == "2":
    print ("The ISBN Calculator will now close, thank you for using!")
    time.sleep(1.5)
    exit()


elif mainmenu == "1":
    ISBN = input(" Please enter the 10 digit number exactly\n")
    Digit1 = int(ISBN[0])*11
    Digit2 = int(ISBN[1])*10
    Digit3 = int(ISBN[2])*9
    Digit4 = int(ISBN[3])*8
    Digit5 = int(ISBN[4])*7
    Digit6 = int(ISBN[5])*6
    Digit7 = int(ISBN[6])*5
    Digit8 = int(ISBN[7])*4
    Digit9 = int(ISBN[8])*3
    Digit10 = int(ISBN[9])*2

    sum=(Digit1+Digit2+Digit3+Digit4+Digit5+Digit6+Digit7+Digit8+Digit9+Digit10)

    num=sum%11
    Digit11=11-num
    if Digit11==10:
        Digit11='X'
        ISBNNumber=str(ISBN)+str(Digit11)
        print('The ISBN number is -->    ' + ISBNNumber)
```

Note. This code is just work code, not a good implementation.

Comment: I used it but whenver I type in the new number nothing comes up...thank you im very new to this

Comment: @user3584526 Which ISBN typed in? My testing ISBN was 8979143400 and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Why the line:

```
(mainmenu)
```

?

In your if statements remove the ():

```
if mainmenu == "1":
    ...
elif mainmenu == "2":
    ...
else:
    print("Invalid menu option")
    exit()
```

Comment: That shouldn't change anything.

Comment: Thank you but digit 1 is still not defined:P

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs when you execute that code with Python 2. Use Python 3 instead.

In Python 2, `input` *evaluates* the input you provide, so if you enter `1`, then `mainmenu` is `1` (the number) and not `"1"` (the string), thus both of your `if`-checks fail and your code arrives at the `sum=...` part without any ISBN number being inputted.

Comment: @user3584526 Are you 100% sure you are? Type `python` (without running any program, i.e. interactive mode) and see what it prints on top.

Comment: How do you start your script? Maybe your IDE uses a different version by default. At least that's the only way I can reproduce the problem. Add `import sys; print(sys.version)` to your code. Also, `print(repr(mainmenu))` to see whether it's a string or a number.

Answer (score 0):

As commented above, your "ISBN" is quite different from the standard, which has either 10 or 13 digits including check digit.

A clean implementation for ISBN-10 calculation would be:

```
from string import digits

checkTemplate = digits + "X"

def isbn(isbnBody):
    """append check digit to a isbn given as string without check digit"""
    assert len(isbnBody) == 9
    s = sum([int(isbnChar)*multiplier for isbnChar, multiplier in zip(isbnBody, range(1,10))])
    checkDigit = checkTemplate[s % 11]
    return isbnBody + checkDigit
```